# VB6 regular expression for whitespace remover in HTML

Tags: regex, vb6, vbscript

I'm trying to run this regular expression [\s]+(<)|(>)[\s]+

```
dim myRegExp as object
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.MultiLine = True
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "[\s]+(<)|(>)[\s]+"
'myRegExp.Test (str)
str = myRegExp.Replace(str, "$2$1")
```

this doesn't seem to work

you can test run that regular expression on http://www.regextester.com/
and it work perfectly

It's suppose to remove whitespace from the left and right of HTML Tags to optimize the webpage without removing whitespace in actual text just inbetween html tags.

```
<br>        adsfdf </br> <img    
asdddasd      >


sdfdsf <br>           <yah>43 3453490
90                             <tag>
<tag>
```

turns into

```
<br>adsfdf</br><img asdddasd>sdfdsf<br><yah>43 3453490 90<tag><tag>
```

why doesn't it work in VB6/VBScript? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
myRegExp.Pattern = "\s+(<)|(>)\s+"
str = myRegExp.Replace(str, "$2$1")
```

VB6/VBScript regexes probably don't like `\s` in a character class.

Comment: Probably but it doesn't seem to work no matches found doing myRegExp.Test(str) = false maybe < > has to be with slashes too? idk lol, just tried \s+(\<)|(\>)\s+ doesn't work either

Comment: Try each half of the expression separately.  Maybe it gives different precedence to the `|` operator.  Or start even further back -- test if `\s` works.  Then `\s+`.  Then `\s+<`.  Then `\s+(<)` etc. until you find the part of the expression that chokes.

Comment: omg i'm too tired \s+(<)|(>)\s+ actually works.. I just kept looking at the end of the output which contains javascript code that doesn't get packed so I missjudged the HTML tags are getting compressed just fine.